# Mapping list with transformation returns different value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, I am trying to use a transformation in a more complicated expression while mapping the expression over a list. For some reason using the transformation rule results in a completely different value, but I can't tell why from the documentation.

```
Clear[x, values]

values = {{1}, {2, Null, 3}, {4, 5, Null, 6, Null }}
Out[122]= {{1}, {2, Null, 3}, {4, 5, Null, 6, Null}}

Length[x] /. x -> DeleteCases[#, Null] & /@ values
Out[123]= {0, 0, 0}

Length[DeleteCases[#, Null]] & /@ values
Out[124]= {1, 2, 3}
```

Update:
So far I have been able to figure out that `Length[x]` is a valid expression even when `x` is not defined, because the argument to `Length[]` is an expression that returns the number of components in that expression. Now I need to understand how to delay evaluation until after `x` has been substituted.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept. I hope to see you on [Mathematica.SE], which I notice you signed up for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the replacement before the left-hand-side is evaluated you can use `Unevaluated`:

```
Unevaluated[Length[x]] /. x -> DeleteCases[#, Null] & /@ values
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

Read [Working with Unevaluated Expressions](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/) by Robby Villegas for a detailed understanding of this head.

---

Dedicated StackExchange site:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you might define your own length function that evaluates only for a list (or whatever)

```
length[v_List] := Length[v]
length[x] /. x -> DeleteCases[#, Null] & /@ values
```

(* 1 2 3 *)

or perhaps to be more general..

```
length[v_ /; Head[v] =!= Symbol] := Length[v]
```

Comment: That does seem to work in some contexts, although in mine Mathematica was complaining because I was using it as an argument to a function and the heads didn't match between this expression and the other argument.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to prevent early evaluation of the expression using `Hold[]` and `ReleaseHold[]`.

```
In[229]:= ReleaseHold[Hold[Length[x]] /. x -> {1, 2, 3}]
Out[229]= 3

Length[x] /. x -> {1, 2, 3}
Out[230]= 0
```

In the original question context, here is how I was able to solve it:

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[Length[x]] /. x -> DeleteCases[#, Null]] & /@ values
```